# How to serialize a relation OneToOne in Django with Rest Framework?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, one-to-one

I have a class PersonProfile, and a class Person.
In the class Person i have a relationship OneToOne with PersonProfile.
How can i Serialize that?

```
class PersonProfile(models.Model):
    interests = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    researchLines = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    loginName = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

class Person(models.Model):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(PersonProfile)
    enviroment = models.ForeignKey(Enviroment, related_name="persons")
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create custom serializer fields to create your custom PersonSerializer.
You can add fields to get values from `Enviroment`.

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    interests = serializers.CharField(source='profile.interests')
    researchLines = serializers.CharField(source='profile.researchLines')
    loginName = serializers.CharField(source='profile.loginName')
    # --- FIELDS FOR enviroment 
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('interests', 'researchLines', 'loginName',
                 #-- enviroment fields
                 )
```

You can also use `serializers.ModelSerializer`

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   #-------------------------
```

Comment: in fact i want to know how to serialize the reference OneToOne, that i think that is in ProfilePerson.
Like... ProfilePerson has a Person...or am i wrong?

Comment: For my other classes im using serializers.ModelSerializer

Comment: Look at this way:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7463dce5b0bfcf9b6767

its correct?

Comment: Yeah it seems corrected . also i edited my answer to use ModelSerializer with it .

Answer (score 2):

I recently stumbled upon something similar and here is what I did for serializing the Person which is in OneToOne relation with PersonProfile.

```
class PersonProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PersonProfile
        fields = __all__  # in your case since you are using all fields.

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    person = PersonProfileSerializer(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = __all__

    # Now override the default create method to create a new object.
    # A similar overriding can be done for update as well.
    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Make necessary modifications as per your requirements
        """
        person_profile = PersonProfileSerializer.create(PersonProfileSerializer(), validated_data)
        person, created = Person.objects.create(profile=person_profile)
        return person
```