# I created an extra table extra table in one to one relation with User table. how to show phone field in User registration

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a simple API to get a user register.

I am using the default User table for authentication purpose, created another table called "phone" with one to one relation with User.

[image]

I am trying to add "phone" field just above the password. (I hope the image attached is visible).

**

> Serializer.py

class UserRegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
model = UserDetailsModel
fields = ('phone', 'user')

class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
password = serializers.CharField(max_length=68, min_length=6, write_only=True)

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username','first_name', 'last_name','email','password')
    read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

**

> > models.py<<
> > **
> > class UserDetailsModel(models.Model):

```
phone = models.IntegerField()
balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(),primary_key='email' , on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user)
```

**

> views.py

**
class RegisterView(generics.GenericAPIView):
serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

```
def post(self, request):
    user = request.data
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=user)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()

    user_data = serializer.data

    return Response(user_data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

class DetailsRegisterView(generics.GenericAPIView):
serializer_class = UserRegisterSerializer

```
def post(self, request):
    user = request.data
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=user)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()

    user_data = serializer.data

    return Response(user_data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**

> urls

**
urlpatterns = [

```
path('',RegisterView.as_view()),
path('details', DetailsRegisterView.as_view())
```

]
**

Answer (score 0):

You probably can use source in a serializer with a FK

```
class RegisterSerializer(...)
    ...
    phone = serializers.CharField(..., source='userdetails.phone')
```

see also : [the doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)

I have some doubt in create case, in a update case this code work fine.

see also : [How to serialize a relation OneToOne in Django with Rest Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804010/how-to-serialize-a-relation-onetoone-in-django-with-rest-framework)

and an other way to resolve your issue : [nested serializer](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/nested-relationships-in-serializers-for-onetoone-fields-in-django-rest-framework-bdb4720d81e6/)

Comment: Thank you. It's working.
Create case needs some changes.

Comment: could you edit the answers with your changes and validate it please ?

Answer (score 0):

Updated code:

> serializers>

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import JsonResponse

from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import UserDetailsModel

class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username','first_name', 'last_name','email','password')
    read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

class UserRegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
user = RegisterSerializer(required=True)

```
class Meta:
    model = UserDetailsModel
    fields = ('phone','user')

def create(self, validated_data):

    user_data = validated_data.pop('user')

    user = RegisterSerializer.create(RegisterSerializer(), validated_data=user_data)

    data, created = UserDetailsModel.objects.update_or_create(user=user,
                        phone=validated_data.pop('phone'))

    return data
```

class DetailView(serializers.ModelSerializer):
user = RegisterSerializer(read_only=True)
class Meta:
model = UserDetailsModel
fields = ('user','phone')

Remaining code stays the same.